# Unable to download some files from internet including Java JDK

Tags: networking, router, internet, download, dell-xps

I am getting "Unknown Network error" after downloading 84% of Windows 10 Upgrade from windows 7. I tried some tips given by superusers but none of them worked.

Also I am getting "Unknown Network error" while downloading 
 1) Java JDK 8u60 (32/64). 
 2) Samsung Kies 3. 
 3) Visual Studio 2015. and many more.

But I downloaded Android Studio which is of 1 GB. Some files takes twice or thrice trials to download.

I am a genuine windows 7 home premium 64 bit user with Dell xps 15 L502X (Early 2011) Laptop and I have a Cable Broadband connection 512 kbps which don't need modem, but I use TP-link 300 Mbps n-wireless router with it.

Comment: This can have many causes. Your wireless connection might drop during the download or a antivirus software could interfere.

Comment: Maybe not because I am trying for nearly 2 months, I called ISP but they are good for nothing. Do they have server issue doing my operation time out?

Comment: This might be the cause too, yes

Answer (score 0):

You should install a download manager, this will enable you to resume aborted downloads. This should work with the majority of files downloaded in your browser.

To rule out your Windows installation or any software installed in it you might consider booting a clean Linux from USB stick.

Shortening the distance between your computer and the modem by plugging in a network cable is also a good approach.

Comment: Live CD is a good approach to do, rest all already did.

Comment: Also I tried downloading CS 2012 3 GB from torrent which took just 40 mins on my 1 Mbps(upgraded now) Internet. And i am sitting next to a router with a cable connected to my laptop. I also Upgraded Nvidia Driver 288 Mb. But stuck on jdk and samsung kies3 & like (some IT things )

Comment: Torrents can handle interruptions and they use parallel connections and tend to be faster. Please mention what you already tried when posting your next question.